# PDF: is it possible to batch replace text-boxes content?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-editors, openoffice

Ok, let me explain the situation:
I have huge pdfs (100 pages with lots of text) that need to be translated.
The pdf has the text in textboxes and these textboxes are scattered everywhere.

The ideal and fastest solution would be this: a tool that lists from the left all the text boxes, and from the right has the empty text boxes for the replacement text.

Is this possible? If not in pdf editors, in any other editor (office, libreoffice etc.)?

Comment: Are they "textbox" form fields with editable text, or just text in the PDF with boxes around them? 

Do you need to manually replace all of the text, or is there some algorithm that you can use?

Comment: They have editable text, and all this text(s) must be replaced (translated). The "ideal" solution I proposed, if exists, would make this process easy.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... I disagree. I think a method to extract things out of a PDF would be very hard to write.
People have written WHOLE-PDF conversion software (that does WHOLE ones instead of just parts) and that makes more sense.

Are you sure the text is stored in the PDF as text? If so, there are many PDF re-formatters that will turn this PDF to Word file, even without installation.

When I need to translate PDF, I google: "online pdf converter". I pick the one that looks legit, get my PDF in a nice format and click away.

Heck, sometimes I won't even bother and just open the PDF and read the text as it is.